# Control Cache from Front End

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I would like to control the cache from the front end when certain calls are made in `PracticeUpdate`.

For example, when calling `/api/GetAllTags` from the `javascript` function `GetAllTags`, I can see in Fiddler that the return header for cache-control is set to no-cache.  Is it possible to modify this in the `api`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is get Access to the `HttpResponseMessage` object of the request. You can do this inside a controller action by asking the `Request` property of the controller to create the response for you:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Then you can access the `CacheControl` object via the `Headers` like so:

```
response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
{
    Public = true, MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};
```

You could also make use of an `ActionFilter` in this scenario, so caching can be applied to an ApiController Action method via an attribute:

```
public class HttpCacheForMinutesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly int _duration;

    public HttpCacheForMinutesAttribute(int duration)
    {
        _duration = duration;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true, MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_duration)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Right you are @FilipW. Have amended the answer to reflect how to get access to the Response object.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the reply. Is there any way I could set it from client Side Java Script. I mean to ask , right in the browser ? So, that I can set it Client side without redeploying the app.

Comment: Assuming you still want the browser to do the caching, you could just pass an integer argument with the request parameters, and set the MaxAge property to be that value.

Comment: you can use this library to do all this work for you - https://github.com/filipw/aspnetwebapi-outputcache

Answer (score 0):

Default caching policy for Web API is no caching.

You can add the caching into each action or just use a framework to do that for you such as [CacheCow](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow) which is full implementation of HTTP caching in both client (when you use `HttpClient`) and server.